# Looking for ScrollChangeListener for List View in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I need to scroll a list view on one of the screen in my Android app. I did not find any `scrollChangeListener` which could be used in this case. I need to know the `scrollY` element and also the direction of scroll(up/down). The project uses minimum Android API as 11.

I did come across `OnScrollChangeListener` but its for API level 23.

Could someone please help?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Currently the code is implementing OnScrollListener and overriding method: public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { }. However, it does not give any information about how much we have scrolled and neither the direction. I am looking for some API which tells me about how much has been scrolled vertically and in which direction. I am looking for something what's provided in OnScrollChangeListener Interface.

Comment: Please include the code, marked as code, in the question.